# Load Data via WebRequst on StartUp

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone, webrequest

I want to load data from the web, when my application starts, and
actually wait for the data, because the data will affect the Apps Appearance.

I am using WindowsPhone and c#.

The Problem I have is, that all WebRequest.BeginGetResponse type methods are Asynchronous, 
but when I block my main Thread to wait for a result, the "asynchronous" method seems to be blocked to.

Is there an easy way to wait for the result? 
Maybe an API that allows better control at Downloading files from the web?

Comment: Without having more context, this seems ill-advised. What is your plan for when the web service stalls or times out, or if the user is in airplane mode? If you absolutely must do this, would it be possible to show a generically-styled loading screen that would look acceptable regardless of the result of the web call?

Comment: the data i intend to download is cached. But everytime the apps starts, it should check if theres a new version online and if there is, download it. And then I want to have the new data and parse it to construct the pages based on it. There will be a timeout, so that after 3 seconds or so, download is aborted and cached version will be used. this download should appear while the loading screen is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your response in the comment above, I would recommend the following:

- Show your splashscreen if you have one, then a loading screen.
- *Don't block the UI thread*, for three reasons:

  - You don't need to
  - You need the UI thread to keep going so you can show indeterminate progress or some other type of loading animation
  - Windows Phone will kill your app if the UI thread is locked for a certain amount of time
- After you've loaded your loading screen, start your **BeginGetResponse**.
- After **EndGetResponse** is completed, do what you need to and then navigate to the main page of the application.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. I followed your advice and I actually got it to work ;)